# `window.ScrollTo(...)` in a `mousemove` event gives horrible janky scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I've got a custom scrollbar solution ([view on CodePen](https://codepen.io/ilmiont/pen/axvebz)).

The obvious idea is dragging the custom scrollbar should scroll the page.

Try it and see what happens... it's bizarrely janky, and the scrollbar and page scrolling will suddenly snap between points.

The scrolling process is currently in a `mousemove` handler:

- update the scrollbar position visually
- `window.scrollTo(...)` the new position, calculated as viewport `top` relative to the new scrollbar position

If I comment out the `window.scrollTo(...)` line, the scrollbar itself then moves perfectly smoothly and sticks with the cursor.

**Pertinent code**

```
    mousemove(e) {
        if (!this.active) return;
        this.update(this.getScrollDeltaPositional(e.pageY));
        window.scrollTo({top: this.getWindowScrollTop()});
    }

    update(position, show=true, timer=true, time=0) {
        let track = this.getTrackHeight();
        this.trackPosition = Math.min(Math.max(position, 0), track);
        this.track.style.transform = `translateY(${this.trackPosition}px)`;
    }

    getWindowScrollTop() {
        let scroll = this.getDocumentScroll();
        let position = (this.trackPosition / this.root.clientHeight);
        return Math.round(scroll * position);
    }
```

*(Recommended you view the full source on CodePen)*

I presume the scrolling each `mousemove` is blocking the `mousemove` events, resulting in the sudden snaps being observed.

How to achieve a smooth scrolling effect on `window` using a custom scrollbar?

Comment: FYI if you want to see some sample code or use something that you can customize out of the box, you can get the source code for jQueryUI and it's scrollbars here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui

Answer (score 1):

## I finally found the answer

After far too many hours of trying everything conceivable to remedy this, I stumbled upon this identical problem: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/scrolltop-inexplicably-going-haywire/.

As that user eventually discovered, `MouseEvent.pageY` (which is what I was using to get scroll position) is

> *[relative to the top edge of the viewport, including scroll offsets](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents.shtml)*.

Therefore, the scroll movement effectively amplifies the `mousemove` events, causing the scrolling to accelerate exponentially as seen in the demo.

So after half a day of hacking about with this, the fix is a simple Ctrl+H... use **`MouseEvent.clientY`** instead.